# Recursive Number Sequence

Tags: java, recursion, sequence

I want to make a program to output this number sequence: (2),(5),(11),(23),...
where x<sup>i</sup> = 2*x<sup>i-1</sup> + 1, and x<sup>0</sup>=2.

Here's my code:

```
    public static int num(int n){
        if(n <= 0)
            return 2;
        else
            return ((2 * 2)+1);

    }
```

I'm having trouble finding a way to output the numbers 11, 23 and onwards. Would it work if I set a counter variable and continuously loop around the second return statement?

Comment: `return ((2 * num(n-1))+1);`

Comment: check what you are returning, you should use `n` there so `return ((2 * 2) +1);` should be `return ((2 * num(n-1))+1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well seeing as you want it to be recursive, let's make it recursive!

```
public static int num(int n){
    if(n <= 0)
        return 2;
    else
        return (2 * num(n-1))+1; //Recursive call here
}
```

With a quick runnable method to check it:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println("num(" + i + ")=" + num(i));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
num(0)=2
num(1)=5
num(2)=11
num(3)=23
num(4)=47
num(5)=95
num(6)=191
num(7)=383
num(8)=767
num(9)=1535
```